# How to use the components from PCA in discriminant analysis?

Tags: pca, sas

Any clue on how to do this in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is canonical discriminant analysis the same as DAPC (Discriminant Analysis on Principal Components)?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138721/is-canonical-discriminant-analysis-the-same-as-dapc-discriminant-analysis-on-pr)

Comment: Run the PCA and store the PC in a dataset. Then use those in your DA. Problem is interpretation.